# 1-button Garage Remotes open/close door but won’t stop part way

Tags: garage, remote-control

Due to water damage, my Overhead garage opener’s logic board had to be replaced in January. Since then, or actually since the weather has warmed up in the past couple of weeks, I’ve found that neither of my mini 1-button Genie 1995-on aftermarket remotes purchased in October stops the door midstream, except occasionally at one spot three feet off the ground if I’m standing outside. As I recall, they did stop the door prior to the board change. Batteries aren’t the issue. OTOH, the previously installed Overhead wall switches inside the door, in the stairwell and on the car visor all work fine. Any idea what may have changed?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a garage door that stopped before hitting its limit switches unless it's malfunctioning or has been told to go the other direction.

Comment: `Since then, or actually since the weather has warmed up` ... which is it?

Comment: `if I’m standing outside` ... what happens if you stand inside the garage?

Comment: Unscrew the light bulb from the opener and see if that makes a difference. If it now works, get a non-interfering LED bulb made for openers or use an incandescent.

Comment: I’m in SW Montana and it was a cold very snowy winter. Had no reason to stop it part way until the temp rose enough to let the warm air in. Electricity is expensive here. No success from inside garage with those remotes. Will check bulb. @keshlam Been here 15 years and door has always stopped where desired.

Comment: OK. If it still works as you expect with the original remote, the problem is that the second-source remotes aren't transmitting exactly the same codes in exactly the same way. In which case,  all you can do is find second-source remotes which work more happily with your system, or get OEM remotes that will work exactly as designed for your system, or accept the problem, or replace the whole system, or do lots of electronic debugging to try to understand what the difference is and build your own remote...

Comment: My garage door also stops in any desired position, going up or going down. I would say your replacement logic board is faulty.

Comment: Your remote is fine, it works. It only sends one type of signal to the controller. That could be the stop signal if the door is moving. The same signal also opens/closes the door. The logic board decides what to do.

Comment: A correction: The Overhead multi-button visor remote doesn’t stop the door either, at least from outside the garage. If it’s the logic board, why with the two wired wall units, but not the remotes?